# What does npm run bundle do?

Tags: npm

I'm trying to understand and follows https://github.com/DMPRoadmap/roadmap/wiki/Installation

But I don't understand something they use.

What does these do?

1) `npm run bundle`

I know it equals to `npm run-script bundle` as according to [npm doc about run script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) but I don't really understand where the bundle come from; in other words, I don't understand what [npm doc about run script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) mean by

> an arbitrary command from a package's script object

2) `npm run bundle -- -p`

Since I don't know where the `bundle` come from, I don't know how to work out the meaning of `-- -p` option. I want to find its documentation and see the details.

I'm not sure if [npm doc about bundle](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/bundle) is related, but it seems to be replaced by `install` as documented in [npm doc about install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install).

And why is this option got so many `-` characters (3 in this case) before `p`? I normally see 2 `-` for long option name and 1 `-` for abbreviated option name

Comment: It's not well worded but `an arbitrary command from a package's script object` means a command line string found inside the "script" section of the project's package.json file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any time you see npm run [x] anywhere it means that it's executing a command located in the scripts section of the package.json file. Therefore npm run bundle runs the bundle command located here: https://github.com/DMPRoadmap/roadmap/blob/master/lib/assets/package.json#L8 which in this case looks like all it's doing is running webpack

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/karma start",
    "bundle": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack",
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint --ext .js --cache ./javascripts/ || true"
  }
```

Comment: I also see this "If you prefer to daemonize Webpack please use npm run bundle -- -p instead", do you know what the p options means? Why we have '--' before '-p' and where we can find documentation about it?

Comment: According to https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script npm will pass all the arguments after the -- directly to your script. So in this case, it's passing the -p command to webpack and in webpack, -p is a shortcut for running: --optimize-minimize --define process.env.NODE_ENV="production"